Export Mule Project - Cannot invoke org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystem.newLocalRepositoryManager
When I do the export of a project this error happens:
Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystem.newLocalRepositoryManager(org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystemSession, org.eclipse.aether.repository.LocalRepository)" because "repositorySystem" is null 

I'm using:

Anypoint Studio 7.19
Mule Runtime 4.6.9
MMP (Mule Maven Plugin) 3.2.0

I need to succeed at exporting a simple project (proxy) using the latest LTS Runtime 4.6.9

You are using a very old version of the Mule Maven Plugin. Version 3.2.0 was released in 2018. That version is not compatible with Mule 4.5 o newer, as the Mule Maven Plugin 3.2.0 release notes say. Use the latest release available.

I changed to 4.1.1 and it worked. Thanks. I didn't try some recent version, it should also work, I think.

I advise to use the latest version. You are missing bug fixes and potential compatibility with future releases.
